# Oracle query aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables name employee_1 and mobile_1 in oracle
empolyee_1 data is

```
  Mobile_No  Sim_No      Start_Date         End_Date 
1111111113  1111112222  11/10/2017 21:02:44 13/10/2017 21:02:44
1111111111  1212121212  3/10/2017 21:02:44  10/10/2017 21:02:44
1111111111  1111111111  11/10/2017 21:02:44 13/10/2017 21:02:44
1111111111  1111111112  11/10/2017 21:02:44 13/10/2017 21:02:44
1111111111  1111111111  12/10/2017 21:02:44
```

Mobile_1 data is

```
  Mobile_No  Status
1111111111  connected
1111111112  connected
```

I want to retrieve all the 4 columns of first table.
Condition is empolyee_1.mobile_No = Mobile_1.mobile_no with maximum start date.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000908/oracle-sql-query-retrieve-latest-values-per-group-based-on-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, please check it out...

```
select mobile_no,sim_no,start_date,end_date from(
select mobile_no,sim_no,start_date,end_date,rank() over(partition by mobile_no,sim_no order by start_date desc) rn from employee_1)s
where rn=1
and exists (select 1 from mobile_1 m where m.Mobile_No = s.mobile_no);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. you have saved my day. looks like i am learning fast from your logic . great help thnx again Vivek.

Comment: most welcome, I am happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` may be used :

```
select e1.* 
  from employee_1 e1 
  inner join ( select mobile_no, max(e.start_date) start_date from employee_1 e group by mobile_no ) e2 
          on ( e1.mobile_no = e2.mobile_no and e1.start_date = e2.start_date )
  inner join mobile_1 m
          on ( m.mobile_no = e1.mobile_no );
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b267f1/1)

Comment: thnx Bararos...

Comment: @Mayur you're welcome friend. By the way, the other replier(`user8406805`) seems been deleted.

Comment: yes.. it has solved my problem.