# Pull latest record in table with duplicate ID's

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

| ID | DATE | col1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2022 | apple |
| 1 | 01-02-2022 | orange |

It's been a while since I've worked with sql (using oracle fyi). If I want to pull unique ID's with the latest Date (in this case only the second row should be pulled in the result), how can I do that?

I tried:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(DATE), col1
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```

Now this doesn't work because I need to aggregate col1 in the SELECT or throw it in the GROUP BY. If I throw it in the GROUP BY, I'll get both rows in the result, right? But I also don't see the point in aggregating col1 if I want the row based on max(date). Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL query: Retrieve latest values per group based on time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000908/oracle-sql-query-retrieve-latest-values-per-group-based-on-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **LAG()**, **LEAD()** **ROW_NUMBER()** function to achieve this goal. Check my below queries.

**Using LAG():**

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    DATE, 
    col1
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        LAG(DATE, 1) OVER(Partition By ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS DateOfPreviousRow
     FROM Table
) T
WHERE DateOfPreviousRow IS NULL
```

**Using LEAD():**

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    DATE, 
    col1
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        LEAD(DATE, 1) OVER(Partition By ID ORDER BY DATE) AS DateOfPreviousRow
    FROM Table
) T
WHERE DateOfPreviousRow IS NULL
```

**Using ROW_NUMBER():**

```
SELECT T.* FROM 
(
   SELECT 
       *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS ROWNumber
   FROM Table
) T
WHERE ROWNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by date desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```