# Oracle SQL query to select only records with date earliest on Department Table

Tags: sql, oracle

If time difference for 'Login_Date' column with records for same Department is within 18 hours then pick only the record with earliest login date.

Below sample data:

[image]

Need query for below data:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share what have you done so far in order to solve the problem by using sample data as text, but not images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL query: Retrieve latest values per group based on time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000908/oracle-sql-query-retrieve-latest-values-per-group-based-on-time)

Comment: @astentx No, it is not asking for the first row of each group. It is asking to exclude rows that are within 18 hours of a previous row.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to do row-by-row processing if you want to exclude all rows that are within 18 hours of the first row of the group:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY department
  ORDER     BY login_date
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (first_row {- within_18_hours* -} )
  DEFINE
    within_18_hours AS login_date <= first_row.login_date + INTERVAL '18' HOUR
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (record_id, department, "USER", login_date) AS
SELECT 1, 'IT',      'xujk', DATE '2022-01-10' + INTERVAL '10' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'IT',      'jkl',  DATE '2022-01-10' + INTERVAL '15' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'IT',      'xujk', DATE '2022-01-12' + INTERVAL '11' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'FINANCE', 'mno',  DATE '2022-01-10' + INTERVAL '01' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'FINANCE', 'abc',  DATE '2022-01-12' + INTERVAL '15' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'FINANCE', 'def',  DATE '2022-01-12' + INTERVAL '20' HOUR FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DEPARTMENT | LOGIN_DATE | RECORD_ID | USER |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | FINANCE | 10-JAN-22 | 4 | mno |
> | FINANCE | 12-JAN-22 | 5 | abc |
> | IT | 10-JAN-22 | 1 | xujk |
> | IT | 12-JAN-22 | 3 | xujk |

---

If you want to exclude rows that are within 18 hours of the previous row (and not necessarily within 18 hours of the earliest row of the group) then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY department
  ORDER     BY login_date
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (first_row {- within_18_hours* -} )
  DEFINE
    within_18_hours AS login_date <= PREV(login_date) + INTERVAL '18' HOUR
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=270d9442d47836473d30568797f50476)*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select Record_ID,d.Department,User,d.Login_Date
from data d
inner join ( Select Department,min(Login_Date) 
             from data 
             where EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(Login_Date AS timestamp)) <= 18
             group by Department,trunc(Login_Date) ) as t
on d.Department= t.Department and d.Login_Date = t.Login_Date
```

Comment: But condition handling to include only earliest of those that are within 18 hours. That is not handled here.

Comment: I've edited my answer, check it out.