# Implicit outer apply in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

I am having to work in Oracle SQL and one issue I'm coming across is how to use applies in SQL.  Specifically, hoping someone can help me write the code below to work in SQL.  It's not a great example but I'm trying to figure out if there is a good way to:

1. do implicit applies, referencing columns from the "from" clause table, so they can be used in future applies/joins in the same query without having to do multiple temp tables, CTEs, or inner queries.
2. same question using top 1 in outer applies

Example:

```
--Drop Table #Users Drop Table #UsersLoginAttempts
Create table #Users(Username varchar(10), Password1 int)
Create Table #UsersLoginAttempts (Username varchar(10), Password1 int, AttemptDate date)


insert into #Users Values(' MAllen',123), ('SEllis ',124), ('MChen ',126)
insert into #UsersLoginAttempts Values
          ('MAllen ',123, '20221001'), (' SEllis ',124, '20221001')
        , (' MChen  ',126, '20221001'), ('MAllen ',126, '20221008')
        , (' SEllis ',123, '20221008'), (' MChen',128, '20221008')


Select t.*, u.*
from #Users t
outer apply ( select ltrim(rtrim(t.username)) as UserNameTrim) unt
Outer apply ( select top 1 * from #UsersLoginAttempts ula 
                    where ltrim(rtrim(ula.UserName)) = unt.UserNameTrim
                order by ula.AttemptDate desc) u
```

Comment: Oracle PLSQL is not Microsoft SQL Server (the `sql-server` tag), please fix your tags.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Oracle? PL/SQL *means* "Oracle". Because, you can't name tables that way (with a hash sign), INSERT INTO is wrong, there's no TOP in Oracle ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL query: Retrieve latest values per group based on time \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000908/oracle-sql-query-retrieve-latest-values-per-group-based-on-time) Or [Fetch the rows which have the Max value for a column for each distinct value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-for-a-column-for-each-distinct-value-of)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the first `OUTER APPLY` (and would need to add `FROM DUAL` if you did include it as, in Oracle, all queries must include a table name) and `TOP` is not supported syntax, you can use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` instead:

```sql
Select t.*,
       u.*
from   Users u
       Outer apply (
         select *
         from   UsersLoginAttempts ula 
         where  TRIM(ula.UserName) = TRIM(u.UserName)
         order by ula.AttemptDate desc
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) t
```

Which, for your sample data:

*Note:

- Do not use `#` as the first character of an identifier (otherwise you will need to use quoted identifiers throughout your code).
- Your `INSERT` syntax is not valid for Oracle; use `INSERT ALL ...` OR `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` if you want to insert multiple rows.
- Use `VARCHAR2` and not `VARCHAR`.
- `'20221001'` is not a date; it is a string literal. If you want to insert a date then either use `TO_DATE`, with a format model, to explicitly convert it or use a date literal `DATE '2022-10-01'`.

```
Create table Users (
  Username varchar2(10),
  Password1 int
)

Create Table UsersLoginAttempts (
  Username    varchar2(10),
  Password1   int,
  AttemptDate date
)

insert into Users (username, password1)
  SELECT ' MAllen', 123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SEllis ', 124 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MChen ',  126 FROM DUAL;

insert into UsersLoginAttempts (username, password1, attemptdate)
  SELECT 'MAllen ',  123, DATE '2022-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT ' SEllis ', 124, DATE '2022-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT ' MChen  ', 126, DATE '2022-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MAllen ',  126, DATE '2022-10-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT ' SEllis ', 123, DATE '2022-10-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT ' MChen',   128, DATE '2022-10-08' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| USERNAME | PASSWORD1 | ATTEMPTDATE | USERNAME | PASSWORD1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MAllen | 126 | 08-OCT-22 | MAllen | 123 |
| SEllis | 123 | 08-OCT-22 | SEllis | 124 |
| MChen | 128 | 08-OCT-22 | MChen | 126 |

*Note: this is not PL/SQL, which is Oracle Procedural Language (similar to T-SQL for SQL Server), it is just Oracle's dialect of SQL.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KggWbINJ)