# How do I select the last time modification based on a group with multiple possible results?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out how to make a query show me only when an object has touched a specific systemic location based on time stamp. For example:

```
Query:
SELECT
    id,
    timestamp,
    lp,
    location
FROM
    unit_location
WHERE
    lp IN (
        '1234',
        '9999');

id          timestamp           lp      location
11110000    11-APR-23 15:05:31  1234    Location 2
22220000    11-APR-23 15:22:52  1234    Location 1
33330000    11-APR-23 15:35:10  1234    Location 2
44440000    11-APR-23 15:04:11  9999    Location 2
55550000    11-APR-23 19:29:04  9999    Location 1
66660000    11-APR-23 19:40:14  9999    Location 2
```

How would I make it so that a query could run and it would only bring back the data for the last **timestamp** but only if its location 2 for each individual **lp**?

Example here, it would only show me ID:

```
id          timestamp           lp      location
33330000    11-APR-23 15:35:10  1234    Location 2
66660000    11-APR-23 19:40:14  9999    Location 2
```

I'd tried to use MAX on time stamps based on some where critera and a few other little bits and bats but was not able to replicate the result I needed.

Comment: do not post pictures of data as code.  Post as text, and show your query,  Better yet, set it up on sqlfiddle.com

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Uploaded query into it and better formatted, hope that helps! 

My work network doesn't seem to allow me to use SQLfiddle, apologies!

Comment: Please show sample data and results as text. Please let us know what should happen if the most recent record for an LP is in location 1 — is that LP ignored or is it’s most recent “location 2” record what you want?

Comment: What if you have 2 conflicting records, i.e. records with same LP, same timestamps? Note that **unless** you have a `UNIQUE(lp, timestamp)` constraint, it does not matter for my question whether you think this may happen or not. Without a constraint, you have to assume it will.

Comment: There shouldn't be a case of this occurring @Atmo the particular query for this should be unique location and time stamp for the LP every time it changes location.

Comment: Updated completely - If it's location 1 it should be ignored, or if it's earlier record is location 2 it should be ignored - only the most recent - I hope this helps @pilcrow

Comment: "*There shouldn't be* [a conflict]" really says nothing about your database integrity constraints (as opposed to "There is a constraint preventing that"). I have posted several versions to cope for the lack of details there. Pick the query you prefer using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL query: Retrieve latest values per group based on time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000908/oracle-sql-query-retrieve-latest-values-per-group-based-on-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities for what you are trying to do.
Here are 2 variations of queries using a window function; they differ by how they treat ties.

With `MAX`:

```
SELECT id, timestamp, lp, location
FROM (SELECT unit_location.*, MAX(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY lp) AS last_timestamp
FROM unit_location
) ul
WHERE timestamp = last_timestamp
```

With `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT id, timestamp, lp, location
FROM (SELECT unit_location.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lp ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS timestamp_number
FROM unit_location
) ul
WHERE timestamp_number = 1
```

And here is a version with a `MAX` **aggregate**:

```
SELECT id, timestamp, unit_location.lp, location
FROM unit_location
JOIN (SELECT lp, MAX(timestamp) AS max_timestamp FROM unit_location GROUP BY lp) ul
    ON unit_location.lp = ul.lp AND timestamp = max_timestamp
```

You can choose the least expensive query and/or the query you understand best.